# Rendering charts using local Chart.js in overriding Django templates

Tags: html, django, chart.js

I am trying to add charts to Django admin form with Chart.js. I would like to run my Django website completely offline. Therefore, I downloaded (i.e., copy/past the Chart.js script from the internet and saved the script locally) the js script and saved it in the "templates" folder where I put my overridden Django html pages.

Originally, if I directly quote the JS script like other people do, I am able to render the Chart correctly in my Django admin form. Like the code below

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.5.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
```

However, if I trying to quote the local JS script, I will not get any chart. Like the code below

```
<script src="Downloaded_CHART_JS_script.js"></script>
```

But if I do not rendering the html page from Django, I can see my chart rendering normally. I tried to search through Django reference for several days, but can't find solution so far.

Comment: Did you use `{% static '' %}` ?

Comment: Yea, I tried the `<script src="{%static 'Downloaded_CHART_JS_script.js'%}"></script>`  and read the Django's static help page. Still not able to rendering any chart. 

I think the problem may not be about static file. It is more likely that Django is not refer to the local Chart.js script

Comment: I have tried the absolute path as well, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ene P's comment, I solved the problem by re-reading Django's static reference. Following the reference, create a static folder under my app; put the downloaded Chart.js; use the `{% static '/app_name/script.js' %}; Bingo!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/